# Cannot subscript Dictionary with String

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I wrote the following functions, to access a userInfo dictionary:

```
func updateAddressLabel(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    self.infoLabelAddress.text = userInfo["geocodeLocation"]
}

func updateDispatchInformation(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    let streetName = userInfo["streetName"]
    let incidentLatitude = userInfo["latitude"]
    let incidentLongitude = userInfo["longitude"]

    // Set Dispatch Info Label
    self.infoLabelTitle.text = "Notruf"
    self.infoLabelAddress.text = streetName

    self.createIncidentAnnotation(incidentLatitude, longitude: incidentLongitude)
}
```

But I cannot access the keys, as I get the errors:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary String,AnyObject> with an index of type 'String'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userInfo` is `Dictionary<String,AnyObject>`, to assign the value to a specific type like `String` you have to downcast the object for example

```
self.infoLabelAddress.text = userInfo["geocodeLocation"] as! String
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign `AnyObject` to label's `text` property. I would go:

```
func updateAddressLabel(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>, let geocodeLocation = userInfo["geocodeLocation"] as? String {
        infoLabelAddress.text = geocodeLocation
    }
}
```